# Python 3 binary to hexadecimal with padding

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3 how would I turn binary into a hexadecimal with padding for example "00001111" would equal "0F" i would like it to include a 0 with no 0x attached aswell. I use this to convert binary to hexadecimal:

```
def bin2hex(binary):
return ''.join((hex(int(binary[i:i+8], 2))[2:] for i in range(0, len(binary), 8)))
```

print(bin2hex("00001111"))

Result: "F"

But it does not include a 0.

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake: a hexadecimal character is equivalent to *four* bits, not eight:

```
def bin2hex(binary):
    return ''.join(hex(int(binary[i:i+4], 2))[2:] for i in range(0, len(binary), 4))
```

That being said, I think you make things too complicated, you can simply use Python's string formatting:

```
def bin2hex(binary):
    return '{:02x}'.format(int(binary, 2))
```

Or for an arbitrary number of bits (dividable by 4):

```
def bin2hex(binary):
    return '{:0{}x}'.format(int(binary, 2), len(binary)//4)
```

of for a number of bits that is not *per se* dividable by 4:

```
def bin2hex(binary):
    return '{:0{}x}'.format(int(binary, 2), (len(binary)+3)//4)
```

or with *string interpolation*, like [@HåkenLid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52883498/python-3-binary-to-hexadecimal-with-padding/52883546#comment92680779_52883546) said:

```
def bin2hex(binary):
    return f'{int(binary, 2):0{(len(binary)+3)//4}x}'
```

For example:

```
>>> bin2hex('0001')
'1'
>>> bin2hex('00011100')
'1c'
>>> bin2hex('000111001011')
'1cb'
>>> bin2hex('1101000111001011')
'd1cb'
```

Comment: Your second solution won't work if the binary number has more `0`s at the front

Comment: @Stephen: why not?

Comment: @HåkenLid: he means that it will not write `00f` for `000000001111`.

Comment: @Håken Lid Because the string format of 2 will just add one `0`. If you added 4 more `0`s to the front of his binary number, it would still come out `0f`

Comment: I understand. I didn't catch that part of the question. In the second function, you could also use an f-string if you are using python 3.6 or later: `f'{int(b,2):0{len(b)//4}x}'`

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to do that would be to use the `zfill` string method.

```
def bin2hex(binary):
    return hex(int(binary, 2))[2:].zfill(len(binary)//4)

bin2hex('00001111')
# >>> 0f

bin2hex('000000001111')
# >>> 00f
```